# How do I load JSON attributes pass via knife through chef recipes?

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, knife

I have a web server that basically accepts input for a knife ec2 create server command.

In my knife command, I pass in

```
-j '{"branch":"clone"}'
```

From documentation I thought I would be able to do this in my recipes that are being loaded:

```
@@branch = node['branch']
...
git clone git@github.com/blah -b #{@@branch}
```

However, the git clones are failing because `@@branch` doesn't return. Or atleast the chef logs say begin output of result:

```
git clone git@github.com/blah -b

~Git error showing options and appropriate input~
```

How do I load in my passed JSON attribute? What is the correct way?

Edit:

I manually put in the knife command, and the JSON Attributes seem to load using Ruby hash instead of JSON

`JSON Attributes: {"branch"=>"Air"}`

Last Edit:

My command:

`sudo knife ec2 server create -x ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -I ami-0eca6e67 -d ubuntu-12.04 -j '{ "branch" : "clone" }' -Z us-east-1a -s subnet-6827ec00 -f c1.medium -g sg-bc9d86d0 -r 'role[role]'`

Answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems if I use a bootstrap template that already exists, `-d ubuntu-12.04`, knife ec2 does **NOT** load -j json-attributes.

Get rid of the -d option. Json loads appropriately.

Comment: At least with Chef 11.12.4, you can pass -j json-attributes even if you also pass in a template (-d template).